# How to display Spotify data on a UI using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am building a `C#`
application and I want to display Spotify data on the UI. I have already retrieved the currently playing track using the Spotify API. How can I update the UI with the track name, artist name, song image, and duration? Here's my code so far:

Xaml file:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="av" x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    Title="My App" Height="450" Width="800" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="40"
                                  GlassFrameThickness="0"
                                  NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                                  ResizeBorderThickness="4"
                                  UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Background="#CC808080"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    CornerRadius="10">
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#CC808080" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextColorBrush" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassColor}}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="CustomWindowStyle" />
    </Window.Style>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="80.72" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="82.28" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="105" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="nameTextBlock" Text="Welcome back, {userName}!" FontSize="24" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="159,66,269,83" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Last Login: " FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="0,163,309,0" Grid.RowSpan="2"  />
        <TextBlock x:Name="lastLoginTextBlock" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="91,163,25,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Last Used Programs:" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,38,0,11" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lastUsedProgramsListBox" FontSize="18" Margin="0,82,0,59" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" av:ItemsSource="{av:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>

        <Image x:Name="avatarImageControl" Width="200" Height="200" Margin="0,-50,230,16" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        </Image>

        <TextBlock Text="Currently Playing:" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,70,-5,131" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TrackName}" x:Name="trackNameTextBlock" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="215,76,-5,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="37" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Artist: " FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,110,344,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArtistName}" x:Name="artistNameTextBlock" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="56,113,254,0" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Duration: " FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="156,110,164,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongDuration}" x:Name="songDurationTextBlock" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="236,110,62,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
        <Image x:Name="songImageControl" Width="200" Height="200" Margin="115,45,85,71" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="noSongTextBlock" Text="No song playing" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="{StaticResource TextColorBrush}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        private DateTime _lastLoginTime;
        private List<string> _lastUsedPrograms;
        private readonly SpeechSynthesizer _speechSynthesizer;
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        private string _accessToken;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create a SpeechSynthesizer instance
            _speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            // Retrieve user's name
            string userName = Environment.UserName ?? string.Empty;
            nameTextBlock.Text = $"Welcome back, {userName}!";

            // Say the welcome message
            SayWelcome(userName);

            // Retrieve last login time
            _lastLoginTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon%4Operational.evtx");
            lastLoginTextBlock.Text = $"{_lastLoginTime}";

            // Retrieve list of programs used on last login
            _lastUsedPrograms = new List<string>();
            var eventLog = new EventLog("Security", ".");
            var entries = eventLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(x => x.TimeGenerated > _lastLoginTime && x.InstanceId == 4624 && x.UserName == userName);
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                var message = entry.Message;
                int startIndex = message.IndexOf("NewProcessId=") + 13;
                int endIndex = message.IndexOf(',', startIndex);
                string processId = message.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
                var processName = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(processId)).ProcessName;
                if (!_lastUsedPrograms.Contains(processName))
                {
                    _lastUsedPrograms.Add(processName);
                }
            }

            lastUsedProgramsListBox.Items.Clear(); // Clear existing items
            lastUsedProgramsListBox.ItemsSource = _lastUsedPrograms;
            lastUsedProgramsListBox.SelectionChanged += LastUsedProgramsListBox_SelectionChanged;

            // Retrieve the user's avatar profile picture
            string userProfileImagePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string avatarImagePath = Path.Combine(userProfileImagePath, @"AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures\user.jpg");


            // Check if the avatar image file exists
            if (File.Exists(avatarImagePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Uri.TryCreate(avatarImagePath, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri? avatarImageUri))
                    {
                        BitmapImage avatarImage = new BitmapImage(avatarImageUri);
                        avatarImageControl.Source = avatarImage;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle the invalid URI case
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Handle any exceptions that occur during image loading
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the case when the avatar image file does not exist
            }

            // Initialize the HttpClient
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _accessToken = string.Empty;
            Task.Run(() => InitializeSpotify());

            // Bind the properties to the corresponding elements in the UI
            trackNameTextBlock.DataContext = this;
            artistNameTextBlock.DataContext = this;
            songDurationTextBlock.DataContext = this;
            songImageControl.DataContext = this;

            // Start retrieving and displaying the currently playing track
            Task.Run(() => RetrieveAndDisplayCurrentlyPlayingTrack());
        }

        public string? TrackName { get; set; }
        public string? ArtistName { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? SongDuration { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage? SongImage { get; set; }

        private async Task InitializeSpotify()
        {
            string clientId = "ee07bfeb35b44b188b2dce37f278a6c7";
            string clientSecret = "28a640d1265b4344a63540fec3be467d";
            string credentials = $"{clientId}:{clientSecret}";
            byte[] credentialsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
            string base64Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(credentialsBytes);

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Credentials);

            // Retrieve the access token
            var tokenRequest = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }
    };

            var tokenResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenRequest));
            var tokenResponseContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var tokenData = JObject.Parse(tokenResponseContent);

            _accessToken = tokenData?["access_token"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }



        private void SayWelcome(string userName)
        {
            string welcomeMessage = $"Welcome back, {userName}! I'm your personal assistant. How can I assist you today?";
            _speechSynthesizer.Speak(welcomeMessage);
        }

        private void LastUsedProgramsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lastUsedProgramsListBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string? selectedProgram = lastUsedProgramsListBox.SelectedItem?.ToString();
                if (selectedProgram != null)
                {
                    string programMessage = $"You last used {selectedProgram}. How can I assist you with {selectedProgram}?";
                    _speechSynthesizer.Speak(programMessage);
                }
            }
        }


        private async Task RetrieveAndDisplayCurrentlyPlayingTrack()
        {
            // Make an API request to retrieve the currently playing track
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing");
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);

            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(content); // Log the API response content to the console

                var trackObject = JObject.Parse(content);
                if (trackObject.TryGetValue("item", out var itemToken) && itemToken != null)
                {
                    var track = itemToken.ToObject<Track>();

                    // Retrieve the track name and artist name
                    string? trackName = track.Name ?? "Unknown";
                    string? artistName = track.Artists?.First()?.Name;

                    // Update the UI with the track and artist information
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        TrackName = trackName;
                        ArtistName = artistName;
                    });

                    // Retrieve the song image
                    string? imageUrl = track.Album?.Images?.First()?.Url;

                    // Create a BitmapImage from the song image URL
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
                    {
                        BitmapImage songImage = new BitmapImage();
                        songImage.BeginInit();
                        songImage.UriSource = new Uri(imageUrl);
                        songImage.EndInit();

                        // Assign the song image to the Image control
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            SongImage = songImage;
                        });
                    }

                    // Retrieve the song duration
                    TimeSpan? songDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(track.DurationMs);

                    // Update the UI with the song duration
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        SongDuration = songDuration;
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the case when the API request is not successful
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _speechSynthesizer?.Dispose();
            _httpClient?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public class Track
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public List<Artist>? Artists { get; set; }
        public Album? Album { get; set; }
        public int DurationMs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Artist
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Album
    {
        public List<Image>? Images { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string? Url { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I would like to know the best approach to update the UI with the Spotify data in real-time. Specifically, I want to display the following information on the UI:

- Track name
- Artist name
- Song image (album cover)
- Duration

I'm using `C#` for my application. Are there any libraries or techniques I can use to accomplish this? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

spotfiy not offically package gave alots of errors and restsharp gave alots of errors and I expected it to pull the data and put it in the ui so it could display on the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are halfway there.

1. You correctly are using bindings to bind the UI values to properties in your data context. E.g.`<TextBlock Text="{Binding TrackName}" ...` will cause the UI to update the textblock's text whenever the `TrackName` property is changed.
2. You are setting the `TrackName` property.
3. You are implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the window's data context

However, you are missing code that bridges setting `TrackName` with notifying the UI that the property has chnaged: you never invoke `PropertyChanged`. Without calling this method, your UI does not know the properties have new values that should cause the UI to update its bindings.

There are several ways to implement this:

1. Manually call `OnPropertyChanged` after updating each property. For example,

```
this.TrackName = "foo";
this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TrackName));
```

2. Use backing fields for each property, and call `OnPropertyChanged` in their setters. E.g.

```
private string trackName;

public string TrackName
{
  get { return this.trackName; }

  private set
  {
    this.trackName = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.TrackName));
  }
}
```

You can simplify this by adding `[CallerMemberName]` to the `OnPropertyChanged` parameter. Then you can just do `this.PropertyChanged()`.

3. Use something like the [Microsoft Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) to simplify a lot of this property changed boilerplate. In particular, your data context (which I suggest you move to a separate class that isn't your window) can extend `ObservableObject`, and then you can use [the ObservableProperty attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty).

Comment: after spotfiy accept my require for refresh token and then I can test the new code using the info you gave me and if it works I will check mark it.

Comment: i tested it out and everything now I'm getting a NoContent error from spotify.